# MongoEngine: Embeddeddocument fields do not take default value as none?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, django-mongodb-engine

I've set the default values for fields in embedded document but when I try to post data it doesn't accept None or Blank values.

Here is what my code looks like-

models.py

```
class MetaData(EmbeddedDocument):
    adcode = StringField(max_length=50, default="", blank=True, Null=True)
    additional_html_below_header = StringField(max_length=50, default="")
    adhoc_plus_disable_pacing = BooleanField(default=False)
    adhoc_plus_has_priority = BooleanField(default=False)
    adhoc_server = StringField(max_length=50, default="")
class LandingPage(Document):
    type = StringField(max_length=50, default="")
    meta_clean_URL_tag = StringField(max_length=50, default="")
    meta_name =  StringField(max_length=50, default="")
    created_time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    new = BooleanField(default=False)
    meta_data = EmbeddedDocumentField(MetaData)
```

serializers.py

```
class MetaDataSerializer(serializers.EmbeddedDocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MetaData

class LandingPageSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
    meta_data = MetaDataSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = LandingPage
```

Is there anything wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: Which version of mongoengine, DRF-mongoengine and DRF you are using?

Comment: DRF is 3.3.3 , mongoengine is 0.10.6 and DRF-mongoengine is also latest.

Comment: Have you tried  [`allow_null=True`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that(allow_null=True) but no luck. Somehow managing this issue from UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MetaDataSerializer(serializers.EmbeddedDocumentSerializer):
        adcode = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True,allow_null=True)
        adhoc_server = serializes.CharField(allow_blank=True,allow_null=True)
        additional_html_below_header = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True,allow_null=True)

        class Meta:
            model = MetaData
```

DRF-mongoengine or for that matter DRF does not allow null and blank values for strings. They need to be explicitly mentioned. The bounds imposed on models do not hold inside serializers.

The above mentioned change should help you maintain the validations as required by you.